# Postgres foreign keys / schema issue

Tags: postgresql

If I create a new schema on the current database (`management`), why does it complain about cross-database references?

```
management=# create schema mgschema;
CREATE SCHEMA

management=# alter table clients add column task_id int null references mgschema.tasks.id;
ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "mgschema.tasks.id"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table clients add column task_id int null references mgschema.tasks.id;
```

The `REFERENCES` syntax in not correct, you should use:

```
REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `references` only expects a table name. The foreign key will then automatically point to the primary key of that table, e.g.

```
alter table clients add column task_id int null references mgschema.tasks;
```

Another alternative is to to specify the table and columns, but not with a single identifier:

```
alter table clients add column task_id int null references mgschema.tasks (id);
```

The second format is needed if the target table has multiple unique constraints.